# Proguard crashes app when trying to send picture with camera

Tags: java, android, proguard, apk, gae-eclipse-plugin

My app is tested and working fine. But when I try to test a release apk, it crashes. I am including my proguard file and the error log I get while testing the release apk. Basically It crashes after I take a picture thru intent and then try to send the picture to a recipient over the internet. Again, my app is working fine: until proguard got into the mix.

A NOTE:

The code that sends the image is a `Runnable` that is started by a `Thread` as in `new Thread(runnable).start()`; very basic stuff. Again, the code works outside of proguard.

My `project.properties` file is using the default android file and mine.

android proguard:

```
# This is a configuration file for ProGuard.
# http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html

-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-verbose

# Optimization is turned off by default. Dex does not like code run
# through the ProGuard optimize and preverify steps (and performs some
# of these optimizations on its own).
-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify
# Note that if you want to enable optimization, you cannot just
# include optimization flags in your own project configuration file;
# instead you will need to point to the
# "proguard-android-optimize.txt" file instead of this one from your
# project.properties file.

-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep public class com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

# For native methods, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#native
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

# keep setters in Views so that animations can still work.
# see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#beans
-keepclassmembers public class * extends android.view.View {
   void set*(***);
   *** get*();
}

# We want to keep methods in Activity that could be used in the XML attribute onClick
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

# For enumeration classes, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#enumerations
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

# The support library contains references to newer platform versions.
# Don't warn about those in case this app is linking against an older
# platform version.  We know about them, and they are safe.
-dontwarn android.support.**
```

project proguard:

```
# My addition

-keepclassmembers class com.mycompany.mygame.** {
    public static <fields>;
}

# -keep public class com.mycompany.mygame.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.mycompany.mygame.**

# -keep public class android.support.** { *; }
-dontwarn android.support.**

# -keep public class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**

# -keep public class com.google.common.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.common.**

# -keep public class org.apache.commons.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.**

# -keep public class org.apache.http.impl.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.http.impl.**

# -keep public class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient { *; }
-dontwarn android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient
```

ERROR LOG:

```
05-03 17:40:45.704: E/CameraApp(5068): [SoundController.java:468:onDestroy()] onDestroy-end, sound_pool release 2/2
05-03 17:40:52.829: E/AndroidRuntime(5327): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-514
05-03 17:40:52.829: E/AndroidRuntime(5327): xb: The chosen LogFactory implementation does not extend LogFactory. Please check your configuration. (Caused by java.lang.ClassCastException: The application has specified that a custom LogFactory implementation should be used but Class 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl' cannot be converted to 'xc'. Please check the custom implementation. Help can be found @http://commons.apache.org/logging/troubleshooting.html.)
05-03 17:40:52.829: E/AndroidRuntime(5327):     at xc.a(Unknown Source)
05-03 17:40:52.829: E/AndroidRuntime(5327):     at xe.run(Unknown Source)
05-03 17:40:52.829: E/AndroidRuntime(5327):     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:45)
05-03 17:40:52.829: E/AndroidRuntime(5327):     at xc.a(Unknown Source)
05-03 17:40:52.829: E/AndroidRuntime(5327):     at xc.a(Unknown Source)
05-03 17:40:52.829: E/AndroidRuntime(5327):     at xc.b(Unknown Source)
05-03 17:40:52.829: E/AndroidRuntime(5327):     at afj.<init>(Unknown Source)
05-03 17:40:52.829: E/AndroidRuntime(5327):     at afr.<init>(Unknown Source)
05-03 17:40:52.829: E/AndroidRuntime(5327):     at gu.a(Unknown Source)
05-03 17:40:52.829: E/AndroidRuntime(5327):     at ha.a(Unknown Source)
05-03 17:40:52.829: E/AndroidRuntime(5327):     at ha.run(Unknown Source)
05-03 17:40:52.829: E/AndroidRuntime(5327):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-03 17:40:52.829: E/AndroidRuntime(5327): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: The application has specified that a custom LogFactory implementation should be used but Class 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl' cannot be converted to 'xc'. Please check the custom implementation. Help can be found @http://commons.apache.org/logging/troubleshooting.html.
05-03 17:40:52.829: E/AndroidRuntime(5327):     ... 12 more
05-03 17:41:13.829: E/Trace(5606): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

Comment: Well done including the logs, but you could have trimmed them back to the crucial part. In this case, see the third-to-last line in the logs for a pretty detailed error message.

Comment: @EdwardFalk I trim it. I see the error. I just don't know what to tell proguard that would fix it. I have been spinning around on this same bug for two days now. I welcome help.

Comment: The code that's failing is inside a `Runnable` as my edit explains.

Comment: http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/examples.html

Comment: @Raghunandan The link you show is where my code is from. Any specific ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The telltale sign is this line:

```
05-03 17:40:52.829: E/AndroidRuntime(5327): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: The application has specified that a custom LogFactory implementation should be used but Class 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl' cannot be converted to 'xc'. Please check the custom implementation. Help can be found @http://commons.apache.org/logging/troubleshooting.html.
```

Looks like some Apache logging's classes have been renamed by Proguard, and from the Proguard config file you have

```
# -keep public class org.apache.commons.** { *; }
```

marked as comment (with '#' prefix), therefore I'd remove '#' in the above line thus telling Proguard to not rename classes within package org.apache.commons, and try again.

Comment: I will try again. But the truth is I started out with all of them uncommented. Then I commented them since the code still failed anyway.

Comment: Do you extend any class from org.apache.commons? If so, they need to be added to Proguard's config file as well.

Comment: It stops crashing. Thank you very much for helping. +1 too.